# Change Image by clicking imageView in getView() of Adapter

Tags: android, android-listview, android-imageview, android-adapter

**Goal:** What i want is when ever i click Image inside a List Item it make changes in

1. Database
2. TextView (As Number of Likes increases)
3. Change Image itself to represent List Item Is Liked.

**Error:** But whenever i click image it makes changes in Database and increases count of corresponding TextView.

```
But it change images of other list items as well than of just clicked item.
```

Pleas help me with following code:

```
public class PopularTabRowAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

List<APIDataModel> videoList;
private Activity activity;
private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
ImageLoader imageloader;
PopularDataSource datasource;
int pos;
ViewHolder holder;
ListView mListView;

public PopularTabRowAdapter(Activity activity,
        List<APIDataModel> videoList, ListView list) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.videoList = videoList;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.activity
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    imageloader = new ImageLoader(activity);
    mListView = list;
    this.datasource = new PopularDataSource(activity);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return videoList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return videoList.get(arg0);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return videoList.get(arg0).getID();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View row = convertView;
    holder = null;
    pos = position;
    if (row == null) {
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popular_tab_custum_row, parent,
                false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.descriptiontxt = (TextView) row
                .findViewById(R.id.decription_popCustomRow);
        holder.listtxt = (TextView) row
                .findViewById(R.id.list_popCustomRow);
        holder.imageView = (ImageView) row
                .findViewById(R.id.image_popCustomRow);
        holder.likeImage = (ImageView) row
                .findViewById(R.id.likimage_popCustRow);
        holder.likeImage.setOnClickListener(likeImageListner);

        holder.numbLike = (TextView) row
                .findViewById(R.id.noLik_popCustRow);
        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    holder.descriptiontxt.setText(videoList.get(position).getDecription());
    holder.listtxt.setText(videoList.get(position).getList());
    imageloader.DisplayImage(ApplicationMain
            .getYouTubeVideoImageURL(videoList.get(position).getURL()),
            holder.imageView);
    holder.numbLike.setText(String.valueOf(videoList.get(position)
            .getNumberOfLikes()));
    if (videoList.get(position).getLikeStatus() == 1) {
        holder.likeImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.like_done);
    }
    return row;
}

OnClickListener likeImageListner = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ViewHolder vh = getViewHolder(v);
        int positionVh = mListView.getPositionForView((View) v.getParent());

        if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, positionVh + "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
            if (videoList.get(positionVh).getLikeStatus() == 0) {
                HitLike like = new HitLike(positionVh, vh.likeImage,
                        vh.numbLike);
                like.execute();
            }
        }
    }
};

public ViewHolder getViewHolder(View v) {
    if (v.getTag() == null) {
        return getViewHolder((View) v.getParent());
    }
    return (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
}

class HitLike extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    ImageView image;
    int position;
    TextView text;

    public HitLike(int position, ImageView image, TextView text) {
        this.position = position;
        this.image = image;
        this.text = text;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        activity.setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();
        String responce = sh.makeServiceCall(
                ApplicationMain.Instance.getPOPLikeAPI(),
                ServiceHandler.POST);
        Log.i("PopularRowAdapterResponce", responce);
        return responce;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        activity.setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
        datasource.open();
        if (datasource.addLike(videoList.get(position).getID(), videoList
                .get(position).getNumberOfLikes())) {
            APIDataModel model = new APIDataModel(videoList.get(position)
                    .getList(), videoList.get(position).getDecription(),
                    videoList.get(position).getURL());
            model.setNumberOfLikes(videoList.get(position)
                    .getNumberOfLikes() + 1);
            model.setLikeStatus(1);
            videoList.set(position, model);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.like_done);
        }
        datasource.close();
    }
}

private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) activity
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager
            .getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView descriptiontxt;
    TextView listtxt;
    ImageView imageView;
    ImageView likeImage;
    TextView numbLike;
}

}
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
image.setImageResource(R.drawable.like_done);
```

and set perticular position image change because of it is in getview and there are viewholder used. so you have to

1) create temp array for selected image like position.

2) put for loop in getview and upto temp size if getview position==temp[i] then

```
   image.setImageResource(R.drawable.like_done);
```

else

```
   image.setImageResource(R.drawable.default);
```

thats it...